# How do I configure postfix on 2 VMs to send/receive emails?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I'm trying to use Postfix to send/receive emails between 2 VMs that are on the same VLAN. I've configured Postfix in them individually and am able to send emails to different users on the respective localhosts. I'm trying to send an email from User A on Client to User B on Server. My ip routes are configured fine, both client and server machines are able to ping each other as well as the internet. But when I try to send an email, it doesn't go through.

```
> 164 Nov 12 11:57:23 shenick101 postfix/error[28092]: 1D97C2A5D:
> to=<server@4.0.0.101>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0,
> dsn=5.1.3, status=bounced (bad address syntax)
```

This is the error displayed in the mail.log file.

**Are there any additional details to add in the main.cf file to facilitate mail transfer between two different machines?**

The my_networks parameter has been set to include the IPs of the machines as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include postfix configuration from both servers?

Comment: @mrc02_kr https://imgur.com/a/AJzGIky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround which I am using. For some reason, the mail command seems to not work.

```
mail -s "Subject" -t user@domain
```

I checked  -  `telnet "ip" 25` on both machines and was able to send emails locally as well as to the other machine, so I decided to write a script that telnets in and sends what I need it to send. I repeat, this is not a complete fix, it is a workaround. My main reason for the emails was to write a robot testcase that sends a specific email and verifies it. That is satisfied by the small script; I don't do anything else with Postfix, so I'm leaving it at that.

Thank you for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

This is, I confess, a guess... but `server@4.0.0.101` is not a valid email address. The correct syntax — which is often disabled, not sure if it is by default in Postfix — is square brackets around the IP address: `server@[4.0.0.101]`. Presumably that's what "bad address syntax" is telling you.

Far more compatible is to set up DNS so that you can use the normal `username@server.domain.com` format.

Comment: Thank you, I tried with my server name but that didn't resolve so I tried with IP instead. I've added an entry for 5.0.0.101 in my /etc/hosts file now and I'm using the name, but that hasn't changed anything.

Comment: @Abbishek which hosts file did you add it to (since you have three, on the host and both VMs)? Also, the error stayed the same?